# Python iteration where a new object set its public variable to the iteration key

Tags: python

I'm quite new to Python (Python 3).
My code is:

```
for gender in ["m", "f"]:
    tmorph = copy.deepcopy(tlemma)
    tmorph.gender = gender
    tlemmas.append(tmorph)
```

There's a more compact way for this code?
Maybe through lambda / comprehension?
Thanks, Leo

Comment: list-comprehensions do not apply well when you want to mutate some state. This is probably the best way to write this.